# foreach external template html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched on the internet, but I can't find the right syntax in javascript or jquery "finally if it's possible" to do for example ->

***test.js***

```
array = {title: 'hihihi',
         Name: 'hahaha',};

array.forEach((array) => { var template = load('test.html')});
    $("#ok").html(template);
```

***test.html***

```
<div id="test">${array.title}</div>
```

***index.html***

```
<div id="ok"></div>
```

is it possible to do this or not?

**UPDATE**

here is the solution I found:

***test.js***

```
    async function writeTemp(arg) {
    var template = "";
        template = await (await fetch('test.html')).text();
            template = eval("`" + template + "`");
            Object.keys(arg).forEach(prez => {
                template;
            });
            $("#ok").html(template);
    }

writeTemp(array);
```

***test.html***

```
<div id="test">${arg.title}</div>
```

***index.html***

```
<div id="ok"></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recommend looking into the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) or using a library like Axios which would allow doing something along those lines. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with `<div id="test">${array.title}</div>`. Maybe a framework/library like Vue, Angular or React is more suited for that kind of use case.

Comment: Array is `[`...`]` your false "array" is an object literal `{`...`}` which is not iterable which is a requirement for any Array method like `.forEach()`. `for...in` loop can be used on a object or you can use `Object.entries()`, `Object.values()`, and `Object.keys()` to get a new array.

Answer (score 1):

I know eval is not much liked but this seems to be the only solution to your question.

```
var array = {
    title: 'hihihi',
    Name: 'hahaha',
};

var template = load('test.html')

template = eval("`" + template + "`");

$("#ok").html(template);
```

Comment: thank you it helped me a lot, the only problem in your code is the load function that I replaced by fetch, because load is forced to be attached to an element of the DOM.